# Is there a standard sequence for gamma, brightness & contrast corrections?

Tags: image, brightness, gamma, contrast

In my application I'm doing gamma, brightness and contrast corrections defined by the user. Now I was wondering whether there is a standard order of doing this or not.

It may sound trivial but I couldn't find anything regarding this. I guess it's possible to get the same result regardless of the order but I just want to be sure in order to make it as intuitive as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most predictable effects can be achieved by using [color matrix](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Transformations0512192005050129AM/Transformations05.aspx). Applying transformations sequentially might result in loss as color overflows during each steps will be irrecoverable.
Alternatively color transformations can be done on higher precision than source data - then order is not important due to gamma, contrast and brightness being luminance transformations only.

Edit: To clarify - order is not important within a single transformation, not to confuse with multiple transformations in sequence.

Comment: The order is important.  For a given set of parameter values, the result will vary depending on the order of the operations.

Comment: Regardless of implementation, contrast and gamma or non-linear operations and changing the order of operation will change the output. A 40% luminance value with +40% brightness (=80%) followed by max contrast will end up 100%, whereas if the contrast is applied first (0%) and then the brightness it will end up 40% again.